# Uploading PDF's on Marklogic

Tags: pdf, marklogic

I want to upload PDFs into a MarkLogic database and build a search engine on it.
Can you advise?

Comment: You can use MLCP to load [XML, JSON, text, several formats of RDF, binaries (including PDF), archives, and delimited text](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/content-pump#id_71112).

Answer (score 3):

This can be done without too much trouble. Actually, it is one of the pre-made sample apps: http://developer.marklogic.com/code/document-discovery

The technology stack of that sample app is a bit outdated since MarkLogic 8, but it is not so difficult to recreate it with a more modern stack using https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-samplestack or https://github.com/marklogic/slush-marklogic-node.

The latter actually comes with an example transform that can be used with a PUT call on /v1/documents to get text and metadata scraped from binary documents such as PDF:

https://github.com/marklogic/slush-marklogic-node/blob/master/app/templates/rest-api/transforms/filter-docs.xqy

Document filtering support many binary formats: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/binary-document-metadata#id_68368

HTH!

Comment: MLCP can be a useful tool to upload an initial set of (binary) documents. See also comment by @dave-cassel above..